# Order of Integral Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

In Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory, They defined the order of Integral Functions.

I was trying to see some examples.

While it is clear that the order of the functions $e^z$ is $1$, $e^{z^2}$ is $2$ and $e^{e^z}$ is $\infty$.

I was wondering how can I find the order of the function $f(z)=z$. I can immediately see that this function has order less than $2$.But I am not sure about the exact order of this. Intutively it seems to be $0$.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Any polynomial has order zero

Comment: @Conrad, Okay. I was also guessing the same but how do I prove it?

Comment: Use the definition - on large $R$ the logarithm of the modulus of the polynomial is about $n\log R$ where $n$ is the degree and is less than $R^a$ for @any $a>0$ (of course $R$ large enough depending on $a$) which pre isely means order zero